# Remove nested object in JSON with rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I'm trying to remove object nested in object in JSON file. However, I can not find any examples on the internet or on the official rapidjson page. My code is written on C++.

I have tried with the following code:

```
const Value& rootObject= document["root"];

const Value& settingsObject = extensionsObject;

settingsObject.RemoveMember();
```

But I am not sure what parameter to pass or how to initialize MemberIterator for exact element (as I already know the name of the object I want to remove).

Here is example of the JSON structure:

```
{
  "root": {
    "settings": {
      "item1": {
        "someInfo": 123
      },
      "item2": {
        "someInfo": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

please chek my code.

```
Value Child_Obj(kObjectType); // creat object to but it inside another object
Child_Obj.SetObject(); // set it

Child_Obj.AddMember("Child Number", Value(15), Document->GetAllocator()); // add to child key and its value

Value Parent_Obj(kObjectType); // creat parent object that will have inside him the child object
Parent_Obj.SetObject(); // set it

Parent_Obj.AddMember("Parent Number", Value(10), Document->GetAllocator()); // add to parent key and its value
Parent_Obj.AddMember("Child", Child_Obj, Document->GetAllocator()); // add child object to parent object , "Child" as key and Child_Obj as value

// now the file looks like this :
/*
{
  "Parent":
  {
    "Parent Number":10, 
    "Child": 
    {
      "Child Number":15
    }
  }
}
*/

// let delete this child
Parent_Obj.RemoveMember("Child"); // here you will give it the key for the object you need to delete

// now its look like this :
/*
{
  "Parent":
  {
    "Parent Number":10,
  }
}
*/

// and for fun , if you want to iterate through object , you can do this :
Value::MemberIterator  it = Parent_Obj.MemberBegin();
for (; it != Parent_Obj.MemberEnd(); ++it)
{
  std::string str = it->name.GetString(); // this will give you the key for current child
}
```